# Django Query with multiple attributes

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-database

How can get below result set ? 
There are method to use AND after WHERE clause .

Is there any method to use OR in Where Clause ?

```
SELECT * FROM college_college WHERE id = 1 OR pub_name = 2
```

Comment: this is basic thing to do, read django tutorial, you will find it

Answer (score 3):

Use the `models.Q` object:

```
from django.db.models import Q
College.objects.filter(Q(id=1)|Q(pub_name=2))
```

More documentation here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects